# Number of terms needed to estimate a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How many terms are required to estimate the sum of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{12(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$$
with an error of less than .005

My first issue is whether my remainder should be .005 or .0045 because of rounding. I'm also confused on how to set the inequality up, because I end up getting $n≤2399$ which makes no sense... Any information on what I should be doing?

**Edit:**
This is what I did
$$|R_n|≤a_{n+1}$$
$$.005≤\frac{12}{(n+1)^2}$$
$$200≥ \frac{(n+1)^2}{12}$$
$$2400≥ (n+1)^2$$
At this point I realized I was doing it incorrectly and stopped($n≤2399$ was gotten in an incorrect way that was another mistake).

Comment: What did you try? How did you get $n \leq 2399$?

Comment: Edited to show what I have done.

Comment: As an aside, see [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: You forgot to take a square root.

Comment: If a square root is take then -49≤n≤47 to the nearest integers. That would mean summing to 3 would give the desired accuracy, which is incorrect.

Comment: Where does the $3$ come from? Taking square roots, you have the required accuracy when $n+1 \geqslant \sqrt{2400}$ (note, your inequalities have the wrong sense, you want $\lvert R_n\rvert \leqslant \lvert a_{n+1}\rvert < 0.005$). Rounding, $n+1\geqslant 49$, or $n \geqslant 48$.

Comment: I understand how to set it up now, but follow up question: Checking the sums manually I found that summing to n=35 gave an error of less than .005. Why does the alternating remainder not give an answer closer to 35?

Comment: @User10793 The reason you're not getting $n=35$ or closer to it is that the true error should be less than $|a_{n+1}|$, because after including this term you will then add a smaller term with different sign which will cancel out somewhat. And then you will include the term after that, which will get you closer to $|a_{n+1}|$ but not quite, because the absolute value of the terms is strictly decreasing. And so forth.